# Vue getters and setters on v-model:

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I have a form that has about 30 fields on it and I would like to do some validations using getters and setters, but you use them in computed and cannot have computed and data values with the same name.

There have been examples where the model and the computed property are the same and the setters set the data model, but this is only with one field as an example. In practice for me to do this would be a decent refactor. Is there a way to maintain my `model` to `data` connection and use getters/setters?

Form- using the library Vue-Form-Generator

```
<form action="#">
  <vue-form-generator
    :schema="schema"
    :model="model"
    options="formOptions"
  >
  </vue-form-generator>
</form>
```

The data property:

```
 data: function () {
  return {
    model:{
        id: "",
        strategyId: Number, 
        name: "",
        symbol: "", 
        symbolPair: "",
        entryType: "", 
        conditionalLongEntryPoint: Number, 
        conditionalShortEntryPoint: Number, 
        entryPrice: Number, 
   ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Modifiers

If you only need validation on whether the user supplies a number in a field where `input type="number"`, this may be what you're looking for.

If you need anything more than that, I would suggest that you set a watch property on the member of `data` that you `v-model` onto and do your validation in that function. For this, you might perform a regex match on the data member that you're inspecting for validity.

What you appear to be asking for is the ability to have getters and setters on a member of data, which is not available out of the box. The closest thing to it would be applying conditional logic for when `get` and `set` methods are called, which would be a part of the `methods` object in your Vue component or root instance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately it's too complex for me to do. I'm going to have to back out of this Vue-Form-Generator and use regular input fields, likely I'm going to write a little form library to do the validation in. Thanks for the help.